# How to save float variables in columns of excel sheet (.xlsx) using python

Tags: python, excel

I am a newbie in Python programming language.
My aim is to save (or write) my output variables i.e a, b and c (as in the following code) in the excel file sheet (.xlsx format)
I have tried the following python code,  for writing my output variables.
I want an output excel file (.xlsx) like this:[See the image of the excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xW2kV.png)
. The code is working fine with the .csv file, but its not working for .xlsx files

Following I want to achieve:

1. I want to save each variable (a,b,c) in different columns of excel sheet
2. I want to give names to each columns in excel sheet as (in each columns a, b, c will be stored, and the three columns name should be Value, Cross-range and A-value respectively)

Could anyone please help me on this ? 
Any suggestions or help regarding this ?

```
n=10 
for i in range(n-1):
    a[i+1] = a[i]-2
    b=a/10
    c=b**2
    file = open("sample-test.xlsx","w")
    for i in range(len(y)):
    iter = "%.3f,%.3f,%.5f\n"%(a[i],b[i],c[i])
    print (iter)
    file.write(iter)
    file.close()
```

Comment: You can't write to an xlsx file as if it was a text file. You'll want to use a library like https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io or https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 2):

Excel files are a binary format (technically it is a .zip file), not a simple text format like a .csv file.  If you want to write to a .xlsx file, there are a number of packages that have that capability.

My preference is for `xlsxwriter`.  It allows you to create a new Excel workbook, write data to it, and add any formatting you want.  I am not sure what your for loop was doing, so I modified it so it would work for this example

```
import xlsxwriter

wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('sample-test.xlsx')
ws = wb.add_worksheet('my sheet')

# write the header in row 0, which is Excel row 1
ws.write_row(0, 0, ['chickens', 'ducks', 'mice'])

n = 10
a = 98
for i in range(n-1):
    a = a * i - 2
    b=a/10
    c=b**2
    ws.write_row(i+1, 0, [a,b,c])

wb.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. If I want to save the variables (say a, b, c) in float format such as %.3f or %.5f, this code will be able to do that ? Could you please provide me your suggestions ?

Comment: @Patrick. Same as in Excel you will need to add a number format. In the case of XlsxWriter see the [set_num_format()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#format-set-num-format) method of the Format object.

Answer (score 0):

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook() 
# grab the active worksheet
ws = wb.active 
# Data can be assigned directly to cells         
ws['A1'] = 42.2
# Rows can also be append
ws.append([1, 2, 3])

# Save the file
wb.save("sample.xlsx")
```